# Android: Is there a way to get string attribute name?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-resources

I need to obtain string attribute name in custom view.

My custom view extends `TextView` and in constructor I need somehow to get `android:text` value. Not just string resource value, but name.

For instance, I need to get "appear" from `<string name="appear">Some text</string>`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ideally you will get the "appear" string resource from  context.getResources().getString(R.string.appear). Just try this.

Comment: I just gotta ask: Why?

Comment: so you wanna get a name of id of textview, rught?

Comment: Why? Ok, because our client want it. We need this _name_ as a key of string in json. Crappy localization... They did not accept classic Android localization approach.

Comment: piotrek1543, I need id of string resource that is assigned to a `TextView` in other words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found out, this works for me.
`getResources().getResourceName(int resid);`